# Mark cells bold with matching partial charachters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that's not working yet.
It is supposed to open an input window where you can enter a text.
Then it should open an window where you can enter the range. 
After both entries the whole workbook should be searched and the whole cell where the partial text is located should be marked bold.
If the cell contains more text than the one you are looking for, it should be marked bold.
Example in the cell there is the text:
"Export Area Asia"

If I only enter "Export Area" in the input window, the cell containing "Export Area Asia" should be marked completely bold.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Zelle_Fett_Wenn_best_Inhalt_Input_Box()
Dim Filtertext As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aRange As Range
On Error Resume Next
  Set aRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter range", Type:=8)
  If aRange Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Operation Cancelled"
  Else
    aRange.Select
  End If

Filtertext = InputBox("Enter Text")
For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Select
x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Rows.Select
If Cells.Value Like Filtertext Then
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
Else
    Selection.Font.Bold = False
End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Maybe somebody would be so nice to correct it so that it works.

Thanks a lot and cheers
Tom

Comment: What are you using `aRange` for? Also, note that `UsedRange` and `Select` are both not really the best ways dealing with this kind of operation. Even then, your `Like` operator needs wildcards and you'd need to iterate over your `Range`. Instead I advise to either use conditional formatting OR `ReplaceFormat`.

Comment: Could you please alter the code please so that it works. I not a pro as you are. I Just need to enter a text in an input box so that all cells in the workbook will be bolded as soon as the partial ext is found in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per my comment, I'd advise against using `.Select` or `UsedRange`. Instead get your last used row and column dynamically. Furthermore, you are missing wildcards in your `Like` operator plus you'd want to iterate over your whole `Range` object.

Next, I'd say you could skip iteration and either use conditional formatting OR use `ReplaceFormat`, for example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, FilterText As String

FilterText = InputBox("Enter Text")
If FilterText = "" Then Exit Sub

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    'Get last used row and column
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Set your range object
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, lc))

    'Set your ReplaceFormat
    With Application.ReplaceFormat
        .Clear
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    'Replace formatting to cells with right criteria
    rng.Font.Bold = False
    rng.Replace What:="*" & FilterText & "*", Replacement:="", SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True

Next ws

End Sub
```

I left out `aRange` since I noticed you never even use it.

Comment: OMG it works perfect. Awsome. Just what I wanted. Thanks a million times

Comment: Thank you very much. The VBA works flawless. I would like to also Mark text that occurs multiple times in the workbook. And I just wanna mark the Area to which i would like to apply the script. And therefore I would like to denominate a specific row or at best multiple rows. That's what I need the range inputbox for.

Comment: @tomstef, it's hard to understand your need from a comment. This is a somewhat older question now. So if you have a different question I suggest opening a new one with your attempt, some sample data and a clear question. Look at [ask] a question with a [mcve] and post a new question =)